# How to show a class elements to main file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I'm building a web app and I separated my menu and homepage in two different files to avoid too many lines of code. I'm trying to call my menu as a class but its not working. It does not show anything from my menu. Do you know a way how can I call my menu. You can find below a little piece of my menu file code and a little part of other file homepage. Please let me now if you have any solution.

```
        class MenuFlutter extends StatefulWidget {
  const MenuFlutter({super.key});

  @override
  State<MenuFlutter> createState() => _MenuFlutterState();
}

class _MenuFlutterState extends State<MenuFlutter> {
  final List<GlobalObjectKey> keyList =
      List.generate(10, (index) => GlobalObjectKey(index));
        
          openPopUpItem() {
            GestureDetector? detector;
            searchForGestureDetector(BuildContext element) {
              element.visitChildElements((element) {
                if (element.widget != null && element.widget is GestureDetector) {
                  detector = element.widget as GestureDetector;
                } else {
                  searchForGestureDetector(element);
                }
              });
            }
        
            searchForGestureDetector(keyList[0].currentContext!);
             detector!.onTap!();
          }
          openPopUpItem1() {
            GestureDetector? detector;
            searchForGestureDetector(BuildContext element) {
              element.visitChildElements((element) {
                if (element.widget != null && element.widget is GestureDetector) {
                  detector = element.widget as GestureDetector;
                } else {
                  searchForGestureDetector(element);
                }
              });
            }
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
            endDrawer: Drawer(
              backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF262533),
              elevation: 10,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 30,
                    ),
                    PopupMenuButton(
                        tooltip: '',
                        child: Text(
                          'Escorts',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 24,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                          ),
```

HOMEPAGE CLASS

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    printInfo(info: Get.height.toString());
    printInfo(info: Get.width.toString());
    child: Row(children: <Widget> [menuflutter()],);
    return Scaffold(
      
      
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
       
        Column(
          children: [
           
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: Get.height * 0.03,
                  left: Get.width * 0.09,
                  right: Get.width * 0.05),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: Get.height / 1600,
                  ),
                  Center(
                      child: myText2(
                    text: 'Willkommen bei Escortme 24',
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                  )),
                  Center(
                      child: MyText3(
                          text: 'Österreichs Escort-Website Nummer eins.',
```

Comment: you are using a stateful widget but it is not returning any widget even doesn't have a build method. please show full code.

Comment: Do you mean for the first file @Manish Dayma ??

Comment: yes. The first file is half here right ?

Comment: it returns Scaffold. I updated my code now @Manish Dayma

Comment: please refactor the name and provide class name with capital first letter for menuflutter class.

Comment: I did. What now @Manish Dayma

Comment: check the debug console if nothing is shown there must be an error log for that.

Comment: I debugged but my menu didn't showed again @Manish Dayma

Comment: have you got any issue in console there must be issue log.

Comment: Locations: No module for http://localhost:55116/dwds/src/injected/client.js it shows only this @ManishDayma

Comment: can you able load your menu class on the main screen instead of showing it on the homepage?

Comment: You mean declaring at main.dart file. I did but it says "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments." @ManishDayma